# django related_name for field clashes

Tags: database, django, orm, django-models, many-to-many

I am getting a field clash in my models:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)

Error: One or more models did not validate:
profiles.visit: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.visit_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
profiles.visit: Accessor for field 'visitor' clashes with related field 'User.visit_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'visitor'.
```

what would be a sensible                     'related_field' to  use on visitor field? This model 
                     basically represents the visits that take place to a 
                     particular user's profile.

Also should I replace any of the ForeignKey's with a ManyToManyField? The logic is a bit confusing.

Edit:
This seems to fix it, but I am unsure if it's what I want. :)

```
 class Visit(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      visitor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='visitors')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a *visit* is a strong concept in your application, then it might make sense to have it the way you defined: *visit consists of a 'user user' and a 'user visitor'*.

If, however, a *visit* is just a way in which *users* relate among themselves, then perhaps you should have a `ManyToMany` relation between *users*. For that purpose you should probably use [ManyToManyField.symmetrical](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) in a [User Profile](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) (in which you extend the information that comes with `auth.models.User`).

In any case, regarding the related_name, you may either [disable the backwards relation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if you won't be accessing the *visits* from the *user*, or use a sensible name such as `visits_to_self` on `user` and `visits_to_others` on `visitor`, which would allow seeing who visited a user by calling `user.visits_to_self` and who the user visited by `user.visits_to_others`.

Answer (score 33):

When you have a `ForeignKey`, it creates a property named with the model name plus `_set` to the referenced model.  The problem here is that both foreign keys want to create a property on `User` named `visit_set`.  The solution is to add related names that are different for each foreign key.

Usually, I use plurals for related names.  In cases like these, I add an "as" clause to the related name:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="visitsAsUser")
     visitor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="visitsAsVisitor")
```

You don't want a `ManyToManyField` unless you can have zero or more visitors per `Visit`, or users per `Visit`.

Comment: To be pedantic, it would probably be better to adhere to Django's naming conventions. So, `"visitsAsUser"` would be something like `"visits_as_user"`. I would personally prefer `"user_visits"`, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Adhering to Django's conventions also keeps things in the admin from looking funny. But I had a lot of code that used the camel case convention at the time, so habit took over.

Comment: Just thought it was worth mentioning :) Naming conventions makes it easier for not only the audience, but the author herself to read code.